# Why am I seeing the error 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'' in my Flutter http API call?

Tags: flutter, api, http

when i run my code have error.
the contents of the error "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'"

Below is my code where the problem occurs

```
class HttpHelper{
   final String urlKey = 'api_key=62ecff60f88bc51146b725ea8c314092';
   final String urlBase = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie';
   final String urlUpcoming = '/upcoming?';
   final String urlLanguage = '&language=ko-KR';

   Future<Album> getUpcoming() async{
    final upcoming = urlBase+urlUpcoming+urlKey+urlLanguage;
    final result = await http
        .get(Uri.parse(upcoming));

    if (result.statusCode == 200) {
      return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(result.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}


class Album {
   final int id;
   final String title;
   final double voteAverage;
   final String releaseDate;
   final String overview;
   final String posterPath;

    const Album({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.voteAverage,
    required this.releaseDate,
    required this.overview,
    required this.posterPath,
  });

    factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      voteAverage: json['voteAverage'],
      releaseDate: json['releaseDate'],
      overview: json['overview'],
      posterPath: json['posterPath'],
    );
  }
}
```

I did deleted some filed and constructor, but have same problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have numerous typos in your `fromJson` - see the corrections below. Also, you have to allow for the possibility that vote average being a whole number (in which case the json decoder makes it an `int`).

The biggest issue is that your API returns you an **array** of albums., rather than just one, and that it is under a key of the top JSON object.

I've shown how to extract the whole list of albums, but just selected the first to avoid changing the method signature.

Finally, from a style point-of-view, avoid creating pointless classes like `HttpHelper`. Its single method could just be a top level function.

```
if (result.statusCode == 200) {
  final decoded = jsonDecode(result.body);
  final results = decoded['results'] as List<dynamic>;
  final albums = results.map<Album>((e) => Album.fromJson(e)).toList();
  return albums.first;
}

class Album {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final double voteAverage;
  final String releaseDate;
  final String overview;
  final String posterPath;

  const Album({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.voteAverage,
    required this.releaseDate,
    required this.overview,
    required this.posterPath,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final num va = json['vote_average'];
    return Album(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      voteAverage: va is double ? va : va.toDouble(),
      releaseDate: json['release_date'],
      overview: json['overview'],
      posterPath: json['poster_path'],
    );
  }
}
```